# Creating a generated field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE example
(

x INT,

y INT,

PRIMARY KEY (x, y));
```

[image]

I am trying to add to this table a new row named Z that calculates the following:

`(1 / count number of times value of x is in the row x) * 100`

As you can see in the picture I provided, my attempt worked but it did not show all 6 rows.
I am trying to show all 6 rows and add Z to the table as a generated field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through a query:

```
select e.*, 100.0 / count(*) over (partition by x) as z
from example e;
```

Window functions are not allowed as generated columns.  You can put this into a view:

```
create view v_example as
    select e.*, 100.0 / count(*) over (partition by x) as z
    from example e;
```

Comment: Is there a way to generate the answers with no decimal points? eg; 25 instead of 25.0000

Comment: You can use `floor()`:  `floor(100 / count(*) over (partition by x)) as z`.